# Trouble setting UIButton to hidden from within an IBAction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, hidden

Okay, I have this code in my `ViewController.m`:

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize generateButton = _generateButton;
@synthesize activityIndicator = _activityIndicator;
@synthesize doneLabel = _doneLabel;

// ...

- (IBAction)buttonPressed
{
    // show activity indicator
    _generateButton.hidden = YES;
    _activityIndicator.hidden = NO;

    NSLog(@"processing starting...");

    // do processor heavy work

    NSLog(@"processing done!");

    // display done message
    _activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
    _doneLabel.hidden = NO;
}

// ...

@end
```

`activityIndicator` and  `doneLabel` are both set to hidden in interface builder. `-(IBAction)buttonPressed` is hooked up to `generateButton` on the `Touch Up Inside` event.

The trouble is that the button doesn't hide whilst the processor works away. It just keeps the default blue pressed state visible until it's finished working, then shows the `doneLabel`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your code is performing the whole process in the same thread.

That thread is blocked until "processor heavy work" is finished

You should perform that "heavy work" in a separate thread and set the state of the button and activity indicator after that separate thread has finished

You can use either **NSThread** to create a new thread to perform the task or call **performSelectorInBackground:withObject:**

Either ways, take a look to the [Threading Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i) in Apple Dev Center

Comment: That sounds pretty good. I haven't touched multithreading yet, but I'll count this as answered. Cheers :)